# Is there a way to make a generic intent with GPS coordinates?

Tags: android, android-intent, location

In my application, when I click on a place, I would like to fire the Intent Chooser that would let the user play with GPS coordinates...

I would like the intent to let the user have the choice between Google Maps, Navigation, StreetView, or any installed GPS....

So far, each one of these apps can be launched with a different intent.. like:

**Navigation:**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=" +mLat+","+mLong));
```

**Google Earth:**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
Uri.parse("geo:"
+ "?q="
+ e.latitude
+ ","
+ e.longitude)));
```

**Google Maps:**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
Uri.parse("geo:"
+ e.latitude
+ ","
+ e.longitude
+ "?q="
+ e.latitude
+ ","
+ e.longitude)));
```

**StreetView:**

Something different

**Navigon:**

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.navigon.START_PUBLIC" />
Location coordinates.
String INTENT_EXTRA_KEY_LATITUDE = "latitude";
String INTENT_EXTRA_KEY_LONGITUDE = "longitude";
```

**Any GPS app:**

Is there a way to use a single intent for all these apps and let the user choose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to use a single intent for all these apps and let the user choose?

Presumably not. You are welcome to use `PackageManager` and `queryIntentActivities()` to build your own chooser that combines the results of various `Intent` objects.